# How should I put this XML object into a javascript dictionary?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-selectors

How should I put this XML object into a javascript dictionary?

XMLcoming in from get_objectives.php:

```
<container>
  <objective>
    <id>1</id>
    <type>thing</type>
    <name>banana</name>
    <date_added>2012-05-08 21:13:01</date_added>
    <released>2012-05-08 22:47:27</released>
  </objective>
  <objective>
    <id>2</id>
    <type>thing</type>
    <name>hammock</name>
    <date_added>2012-05-08 21:13:01</date_added>
    <released>2012-05-08 22:47:27</released>
  </objective>
</container>
```

The javascript that doesn't work, that I"m trying to fix:

```
function updateObjectives(){
  $.post('scripts/get_objectives.php', {}, function(xml){
    $(xml).find("objective").each(function(i){
      objectives[i] = {}
      objectives[i]['id'] = $('id', xml).text()
      console.log("objectives["+i+"].id = "+objectives[i].id)
    })
  })
}
```

Based on the console output below, it appears that the `$('id', xml).text()` call that I am trying isn't stuck inside the function handling the find("objective").each call:

```
objectives[0].id = 12
objectives[1].id = 12
```

Comment: `objectives[i]['id'] = $('this > id', xml).text()`
returns to the console:
`objectives[0].id = `
`objectives[0].id = `

Comment: `objectives[i]['id'] = $('id', this).text()` does the trick! My problem was the ambigious syntax of the $() in the tutorial; $(query, context). Instead of looking for ('this > id', xml) which is
looking for 'this''s child named 'id' inside the full 'xml' file, (I already had found 'this'!) so $('id', this) works because it is looking for 'id' inside 'this' (where 'this' is <objective> tags) I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objectives[i]['id'] = $('id', this).text()` does the trick!

My problem was the ambigious syntax of the `$()` in the tutorial; `$(query, context)`. Instead of looking for `('this > id', xml)` which is looking for 'this''s child named 'id' inside the full 'xml' file, (I already had found 'this'!) so `$('id', this)` works because it is looking for 'id' inside 'this' (where 'this' is  tags) I hope this helps someone!